# TypeScript - Import file and compile into one file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and I have a function within my api namespace `api.ts` file to connect to my api:

```
namespace api
{
    export function connect() : boolean
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the content of my `test.ts`

```
///<reference path="api.ts"/>
api.connect();
```

TypeScript compiles this to two files: `api.js` and `test.js`. Is it possible to compile it to one file called `test.js`, **but compile** `otherPage.ts` **into separate bundle**?

Note:

This is my file structure:

```
- test.ts
- api.ts
- otherPage.ts
```

This is the desired output:

```
- test.js (api.ts and test.ts compiled into one file)
- otherPage.js
```

This is the command I run for auto compiling the file: `tsc --watch`. I prefer a solution where I don't have to change this command specific to the files I want to include.

I'm using the `api.ts` in multiple files, so creating one `ts` file is not an option for me.

**Temporary workaround:**

As temporary workaround, I include the `api.ts` in all my files. This is not a big problem for me, because I compile the javascript file with the Google Closure Compiler, after I compiled my TypeScript to to JavaScript.

I'm using Visual Studio Code, so I can automate this in my `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "windows": {
        "command": "tsc.cmd"
    },
    "args": 
    [
        "res/ts/modules/api.ts",
        "${file}",
        "--outFile", "res/js/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.js",
        "--listFiles", "true"
    ],
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Press ctrl + b to execute it.

Comment: why not create one ts file?

Comment: @AlexeyObukhov I'm using the `api.ts` in multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `--outFile` option in `tsconfig.json`:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outFile": "dist/output.js"
  }
```

or pass it to the compiler like this:

```
tsc test.ts --outFile dist/output.js
```

Comment: This compiles **all** files into one file, including the `otherPage.ts`. I just want `test.ts` and `api.ts` to be compiled into one file.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with `tsc` alone. You can run `tsc` multiple times with different files sets, but it's not an ideal solution. Module bundlers will need to be used for that

Comment: do you consider `webpack`?

Comment: webpack is a bundler system, read about it. If you consider using it, I can provide you with a solution

Answer (score 0):

you could bundle your sources with webpack, gulp, etc.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html

following tutorial in docs link above, you could create a directory, for example `my-app`, 
then in this directory, you run

`npm init`,

then

`npm install -g gulp`

`npm install gulp gulp-typescript --save-dev`

create `src` directory and `gulpfile.js` file, paste following code to `gulpfile.js`

var gulp = require("gulp");
var ts = require("gulp-typescript");

```
gulp.task("default", function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src("src/*.ts")
        .pipe(ts({
              noImplicitAny: true,
              out: "output.js"
        }));
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest("built/local"));
});
```

put your ts sources in src, then run `gulp` command in command line like `Terminal` or `CMD` on Windows

Comment: Can you please provide me some more information? I'm not familiar with webpack, gulp, etc.

Comment: Will the `otherPage.ts` be excluded from `output.js` with this solution?

Comment: please read more about gulp-typescript here: https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript